# Is there any functions in String which can to help delete all spaces in string?

Tags: java, string

Is there any functions in `String` which can to help delete all spaces in string? I wouldn't like to use a method like this.

```
private String deleteSpace(String string) {
    String newString = "";
    for(int i = 0;i < string.length();i++)
        if(string.charAt(i) != ' ')
            newString += String.valueOf(string.charAt(i));
    return newString;
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: There is no `java.util.String`.

Comment: @Rohit Jain What package contains String class?

Comment: String class is in `java.lang`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
// all occurrences with literal arguments
string = string.replace(" ","");
```

or

```
// all occurrences with regular expression arguments
string = string.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Comment: You might want to explain the differences between those two. The second, for example, will also remove tabs.

Comment: @arshajii: you already did thanks, do you want me to explain more?

Answer (score 2):

```
String new_str = my_str.replaceAll("old", "new");
```